# Erro em query ao usar 1 where e 2 joins em Query de busca

Tags: php, mysql, query

Olá, estou rodando a seguinte query no mysql:

```
select * from usuarios where login='gamboamurilo' or email='gamboamurilo@gmail.com' and senha='8b0a60f71e758c8b27e7688ee754cd85' 
inner join permissoes on usuarios.permissoes=permissoes.id 
inner join dados_perfil on usuarios.id=dados_perfil.id_usuario;
```

Porém, está me retornando um erro de sintaxe, porém, mesmo após ler a documentação, não consegui encontrar tal erro, onde ele se encontra e como posso corrigir?

Comment: `WHERE` tem que estar após os `INNER JOIN`

Comment: select * from usuarios
inner join permissoes on usuarios.permissoes=permissoes.id 
inner join dados_perfil on usuarios.id=dados_perfil.id_usuario
where login='gamboamurilo' or email='gamboamurilo@gmail.com' and senha='8b0a60f71e758c8b27e7688ee754cd85';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os INNER JOIN deve aparecer antes das clausulas WHERE.

Eu montaria essa query com a seguinte estrutura:

```
select *
  from usuarios 
 inner join permissoes on usuarios.permissoes=permissoes.id 
 inner join dados_perfil on usuarios.id=dados_perfil.id_usuario
 where (usuarios.login='gamboamurilo'
        or usuarios.email='gamboamurilo@gmail.com')
   and usuarios.senha='8b0a60f71e758c8b27e7688ee754cd85';
```